# The latest technology in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am an ASP.NET developer. What is the latest technology in ASP.NET and also the documentation about it?

Comment: Not everything you write is code mate ;).

Comment: @Younes i ve editted since Rakesh is new to SO...

Answer (score 8):

For MVC it is [ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.asp.net/(S(d35rmemuuono1wvm1gsp2n45))/mvc/) and for web forms it is [ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

That would be ASP.NET 4.0 and ASP.NET MVC 2.0. Documentation? Like ALWAYS, in MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I notice MVC has been suggested, but dont forget to checkout [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) as well for delivering rich interactive application over the web.

Comment: Silverlight is a lot, but it is not part of ASP.NET, which was particularly asked for. I would name it as part of .NET, or web technologies ;)

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers state, MVC is the new thing.

This means that their are now 2 main forms of ASP.NET development: WebForms and MVC

In WebForms, there are only a handful of new things (in VS2010), with support for routing (friendly URLs) the most notable.